# Call Google Geocoding API method synchronouslly

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, synchronous

I need to know marker's address when I change markers postition.

**Basically I have a method:**

```js
function addNewMarker(latLng) {
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latLng}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
                var address = results[0].formatted_address;
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLng, 
                    map: map, 
                    draggable: true,
                    title: address,
                }); 


                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
                    //marker.setTitle(getGeocodeResults(marker.getPosition()));
                    marker.setTitle(***THIS IS NEW ADDRESS OF THIS MARKER***);
                });
            }
        } else {
            alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

**If I extract geocoding code into new method:**

```js
function addNewMarker(latLng){
    var address = getGeocodeResults(latLng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng, 
        map: map, 
        draggable: true,
        title: address,
    }); 


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
        marker.setTitle(getGeocodeResults(marker.getPosition()));
    });
}

function getGeocodeResults(latLng){
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latLng}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
                var address = results[0].formatted_address;
                return address;
            }
        } else {
            alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

I have no luck because this call is asynchronous. And I need that new addres when I stop moving marker. ***Is there a solution to this one?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ANSWER by Original Poster**

[@vale4674 put this as an edit to their question. Copying here as an answer.]

@vale4674 replaced

```js
marker.setTitle(getGeocodeResults(marker.getPosition()));
```

with

```js
setTitle(marker);
```

and added this method:

```js
function setTitle(marker){
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
                var address = results[0].formatted_address;
                marker.setTitle(address);
            }
        } else {
            alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't get it now. Do I have to put the edit in my question or did you do that already with this answer? Don't know the procedure.

Comment: You had put this answer as an edit to your question.  However, answers should be answers, not part of the question.  So I removed it from the question and put it here as an answer.

Comment: More info: You can accept this answer (which, as you probably know, will give me 15 reputation points and give you 2 reputation points).  Or, if you'd prefer to not give the rep points to someone who didn't actually come up with the answer, you can post the answer yourself, and then accept your own answer.  (It's totally OK to accept your own answer, although there may be a waiting period before you can do so. Also, you don't get any reputation points for accepting your own answer.)

Comment: I thought that I can't put answers on my questions. Is this something new?

Comment: To my knowledge, it has always been totally fine to answer your own question, but I could be wrong about that and maybe it is relatively recent.  Regardless, it's mentioned in the FAQ at http://stackoverflow.com/faq: "It’s also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question...."